# Issue while dynamically provisioning volumes on AWS, Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to follow this tutorial to create a Galera cluster using kubernetes on AWS, but I see that the Dynamic provisioning of the volume fails and this is the error I see in kube-controller-manager.log

```
0711 06:12:21.065942       6 aws_ebs.go:434] Provision failed: claim.Spec.Selector is not supported for dynamic provisioning on AWS
I0711 06:12:21.066003       6 pv_controller.go:1312] failed to provision volume for claim "default/mysql-datadir-galera-ss-1" with StorageClass "gp2": claim.Spec.Selector is not supported for dynamic provisioning on AWS
E0711 06:12:21.065942       6 aws_ebs.go:434] Provision failed: claim.Spec.Selector is not supported for dynamic provisioning on AWS
I0711 06:12:21.066227       6 pv_controller.go:1312] failed to provision volume for claim "default/mysql-datadir-galera-ss-0" with StorageClass "gp2": claim.Spec.Selector is not supported for dynamic provisioning on AWS
E0711 06:12:21.066006       6 aws_ebs.go:434] Provision failed: claim.Spec.Selector is not supported for dynamic provisioning on AWS
I0711 06:12:21.066303       6 pv_controller.go:1312] failed to provision volume for claim "default/mysql-datadir-galera-ss-2" with StorageClass "gp2": claim.Spec.Selector is not supported for dynamic provisioning on AWS
```

I am not sure what is wrong, it is using a default storage class of type 'gp2'. Any suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 2):

looks like a configuration issue, "claim.Spec.Selector" should not be set in StorageClass/PVC yaml for AWS.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!